# How to fillna with mode value of a Column with type Float in a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

when I am trying to filling the `NaN` values  with `mode` I have found that it returns `Nan` values again.

```py
df= df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode() if (x.dtypes!=object ) else x.value_counts().index[0] ))
```

Comment: Could you post sample data? ```.apply(...)``` doesn't do what you think it does - in your code I suspect ```df``` has just one column, so inside ```.apply``` ```x``` will represent a single row of ```df``` so taking ```mode``` from it will return value of that single row.

Comment: Why are you using `mode` for `x.dtypes!=object` numeric values?

Comment: my dataframe inclde four columns (three with type object and one with type float)

Comment: why is used `x.value_counts().index[0]` and `x.mode()` ? It is not similar, obviously same?

Comment: the object columns changed correctly , but other columns which have NAN values returned again with NAN values

Comment: No, X.values_counts() for categorial values , while mode for float or integers

Comment: Answer was edited, `x.dtypes` always return `object`, not like you think `floats` or integers. So your solution always retur modes, never run `else x.value_counts().index[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x.mode().item()`

like in your example:

```py
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().item() if (x.dtypes!=object ) else x.va
lue_counts().index[0] ))
```

Note: It only works when the mode is **single or scalar** value. - as remarked by @jezrael

Comment: @Ahmed Safwat Ewida -  I guess you are getting trouble with the only float column in dataframe.

Comment: also , i have found the same results with the following:

Comment: df= df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(max(x.mode().values) if (x.dtypes!=object ) else x.value_counts().index[0] ))

Comment: It could be `x.mode().values` return `array` type.

Comment: Bad solution, here possible `ValueError: ('can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar')`, dont use it.

Comment: also if check `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dtypes)` it return always object, not floats or integers